# intent on Android - pass ArrayList<Drawable> to another activity

Tags: android, android-intent

I have two activity and I want to pass ArrayList -> drawablesFromUrl objs from activity A to activity B. Parts of the code is listed as follow:

In Activity A:

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SitePhotoFullScreen.class);
             Bundle myData = new Bundle();
             myData.putInt("id", position);
             myData.putInt("MaxId", imgAdapter.getCount());
             myData.putSerializable("myObjArray",drawablesFromUrl);<---- this objs
             i.putExtras(myData);
             startActivity(i);
```

In Activity B

```
ArrayList<Drawable> myObjArray = new ArrayList<Drawable>();    
// get intent data
    Intent i = getIntent();
    Bundle myBundle = i.getExtras();
    position = myBundle.getInt("id");
    MaxId = myBundle.getInt("MaxId");
    myObjArray = (ArrayList<Drawable>) i.getSerializableExtra("myObjArray");
```

After execute the code, an error occur :

```
AndroidRuntime(15005): java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel: unable to marshal value android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@4052d928
```

Anyone can help me to solve the problem, thousand thanks!

Comment: As i remember you don't need to serialize drawables and bitmaps...

Comment: but how to transfer drawables and bitmaps from activity A to Activity B? thanks!@

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11387603/how-to-pass-a-arraylistbitmap-between-activities/11387685#11387685

Comment: When you have [`Application` class](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/maintaining-global-application-state), Why you want to send them from one activity to another in bundle.!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass your object via `Parcelable`. Here is a link that will show you how to do that with relative ease:

http://shri.blog.kraya.co.uk/2010/04/26/android-parcel-data-to-pass-between-activities-using-parcelable-classes/