# How to pass Bitmap Array to another activity in Android?

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to pass a ArrayList<Bitmap> between activities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11387603/how-to-pass-a-arraylistbitmap-between-activities)

I want to pass all the Bitmap array elements to another activity, I can pass array list but I can't pass Bitmap Array, is there are any especial instruction for Bitmap Array in Intent?

Comment: please check. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11387603/how-to-pass-a-arraylistbitmap-between-activities

Comment: i just want to pass Bitmap array not Listarray of Bitmap !

Comment: Just convert your `ArrayList` to an array then...

Comment: @PirFahimShah If my answer is helping you then please accept it so it will help others also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below Solution to solve this issue.

1) First Convert Image into Byte Array and then add into arraylist then pass this arraylist into Intent and in next activity get arraylist from bundle and Convert into Image(Bitmap) and set into ImageView.

Convert Bitmap to Byte Array:-

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
```

Then add this byte array into arraylist.

Convert byte array into Bitmap Image:-

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

image.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

Comment: But to pass bitmap array through intent,it is bad practice, so i have used singleton class which does this operation in great manner,

Answer (score 1):

`Bitmap` extends `Parcelable`, which means that you can provide a list like this:

```
    ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmapList = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
    // Poupulate list here

    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("list", bitmapList);
```

Then you can convert this to a `Bitmap[]` in your receiving activity:

```
Bitmap[] bitmapArray = bitmapList.toArray(new Bitmap[bitmapList.size()]);
```

But keep in mind that it's generally bad practice to put too much stuff in your intent. It's preferable to have your data stored (DB, filesystem, singleton,...) and pass URIs or IDs.

Comment: Thanks this seems to be helpful !

Answer (score 0):

//to pass object:

```
   intent.putExtra("MyClass", obj);
```

// to retrieve object in second Activity

```
getIntent().getSerializableExtra("MyClass");
```

Answer (score 0):

use the Bitmap array as static and use classname.bitmaparray in another activity